# Add files from build directory to jar using gradle kotlin

Tags: gradle-kotlin-dsl

I have some files in directory build/schema and I want them to be included in the jar file formed with gradle build kotlin file. How can this be acheived?

Answer (score 0):

##### Add a new resource directory

You can add a new resource directory to the 'main' source set. This is probably the easiest method, both in terms of configuration and compatibility with existing Gradle config.

```kotlin
sourceSets {
    main {
        resources {
            srcDir(layout.buildDirectory.dir("schema"))
        }
    }
}
```

##### Manually amend an existing task.

You can amend the existing Gradle task to include the files. If the files you want to include are generated by a Gradle task, then take care to [properly configure the Gradle task dependencies](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:inferred_task_dependencies) so the Jar task will run after the generation task!

Let's assume that the task you want to edit is called 'jar'. Using the Kotlin DSL accessor we can use

```kotlin
tasks.jar {

}
```

to configure the task. (If your task doesn't have a DSL accessor then try using `tasks.named<Jar>("myJarTaskName").configure { }` instead).

To add files to a Jar task, just use `from()`.

```kotlin
tasks.jar {
  from(layout.buildDirectory.dir("schema"))
}
```

If your schema is generated from a Gradle task (for example, named `generateSchema`), then you should use a [task dependency](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:inferred_task_dependencies) instead.

```kotlin
tasks.jar {
  from(tasks.generateSchema)
}
```

This way, Gradle will know it needs to run the 'generateSchema' task before the Jar task, and it can optimise execution to only run tasks when the inputs or outputs have changed.